# Broken 2D Platformer Flip In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a platformer game in Unity. The character I am using for the player has a very disproportionate and long body, and the player movement script I have implemented doesn't understand where the base of the body is supposed to be(?) Because of this, when the character flips to go in a different direction it seems as if the player is teleporting, even though they are not. I assume that the only way to fix this is to change the position of the player directly after they flip, but either way I don't know how to do that.

```
private void Flip()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1f;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend manually repositioning the sprite in code. I think changing the sprite's pivot point in the sprite editor should fix your problem.
See:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/sprite-is-not-aligned-at-center.493552/

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html